# A strange email: `use gtr`

Tags: cipher

Recently someone emailed me this text. It seems to make no sense.

```
mina ireti ir thandiwe hyn đánh_đố elektron_pochta vyklyk

skip uig & urd
use gtr
```

What does this email say?

Comment: ask Alan Turing, I heard he's pretty good at these

Comment: @Jingle too late now lol

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firstly, the last two lines are

> Instructions.
>  In particular, I think **use gtr** means "use Google Translate" and,
>  **skip uig & urd** means to "skip Uyghur and Urdu" (languages)

Reasoning

> The reason I come to this conclusion is that each term in the first line is a word translated from another language and all of the languages used are from the end of the list on Google Translate (which lists languages alphabetically), hence the instruction to "skip Uyghur and Urdu".

Translation

> Translating the words in the first line is the tricky part but if we start at Zulu and work backwards from each word we get the following (ignoring Western Frisian):
>  mina = **me/I** (Zulu)
>  ireti = **hope** (Yoruba)
>  ir = **you** (Yiddish)
>  thandiwe = **dear/beloved/loved** (Xhosa)
>  hyn = **this** (Welsh)
>  đánh_đố = **puzzling** (Vietnamese)
>  elektron_pochta = **e-mail** (Uzbek)
>  vyklyk = **challenge** (Ukrainian)
>  The final reading is this:
>  **I hope you loved this puzzling e-mail challenge**

***OP note:*** I didn't realize I skipped Western Frisian... an error on my part

Comment: Close, but don’t use the detect language feature. Start at Zulu, then go backwards manually and skip Uyghur and Urdu.

Comment: @matt Thanks for the tip, I think I've got it now.

Comment: Didn't know I skipped Western Frisian, but you got it!